# Select Distinct Records Based on a column, Giving preference for the records based on some other criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables with latitude and longitudes for a common location in ORACLE, I am calculating the distance between those two location and based on it calculating Adherence report. I want to select distict VISITOR_ID row giving preference to the visitor having Adherence as 'N'. Following is the query which i am using and i have also attached a sample output of the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  rv.VISITOR_ID as VISITOR_ID, rv.VISIT_ENT_NAME as Location_Name,

ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(rg.Latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(rv.Latitude)) 
                    + COS(RADIANS(rg.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(rv.Latitude))
                    * COS(RADIANS(rg.Longitude) - RADIANS(rv.Longitude))
                    ) * 6371 AS DISTANCE,

(CASE WHEN ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(rg.Latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(rv.Latitude)) 
                    + COS(RADIANS(rg.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(rv.Latitude))
                    * COS(RADIANS(rg.Longitude) - RADIANS(rv.Longitude))
                    ) * 6371 < 200 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS Adherence

From RANDOM_VISIT rv
LEFT JOIN GEOTAG rg ON rv.VISITOR_ID = rg.CODE;
```

Result of Query:

[image]

Expected Result should be on selecting distinct visitor_id but while selecting distint Giving preference to adherence = 'N':

[image]

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, not images

Comment: What if for a given ID there are no rows with adherence =N? And how to chose among many rows of the same ID all with adherence = N

Comment: if for a given ID there are no rows with adherence =N then other distinct visitor_id would be selected. I have asked to give preference while selecting distinct visitor_id, its not compulsary that every visitor_id will have Adherence = 'N'.

Comment: ok, but what if you have many rows with the same ID and adherence = N? A random one or do you need some logic?

Comment: @ShaileshYadav - The following question applies in two cases: (1) there is a `visitor_id` who has data in the output of your query, but the Adherence is never `'N'`; or (2) for the same `visitor_id` there is more than one result with Adherence = `N`. The question is: OTHER THAN giving preference to `N`, which row should be chosen out of potentially two or more, with the same `visitor_id`? Do you want, as a second rule (after the first rule of giving priority to `N`), to choose the result with the shortest distance? The one with the first `location_name` (alphabetically)? Or just a random one?

Comment: @mathguy - after the first rule of giving priority to N we can select a random one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to simplify, assuming that your query gives that result, this could be a way to get what you need.

```
with yourQuery (visitor_id, location_name, distance, adherence) as
(
    select 5200, 'Mobi Shop', 0.4, 'N' from dual union all
    select 7550, 'Sk cafe', 0.7, 'N' from dual union all
    select 7550, 'DL General', 0.7, 'N' from dual union all
    select 5200, 'Success Mobo', 0.1, 'Y' from dual union all
    select 7550, 'Mack Agency', 0.9, 'N' from dual
)
select visitor_id, location_name, distance, adherence
from (
        select q.*, row_number() over (partition by visitor_id order by adherence) as RN
        from yourQuery q
     )
where RN = 1
```

This has no logic to decide which row to extract if you have many rows with the same `visitor_id`  and `adherence = 'N'`; if you need a logic, you can simply edit the `ORDER BY` part accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

All in a single (additional) query - using Aleksej's sample data:

```
with yourQueryResult (visitor_id, location_name, distance, adherence) as
(
    select 5200, 'Mobi Shop', 0.4, 'N' from dual union all
    select 7550, 'Sk cafe', 0.7, 'N' from dual union all
    select 7550, 'DL General', 0.7, 'N' from dual union all
    select 5200, 'Success Mobo', 0.1, 'Y' from dual union all
    select 7550, 'Mack Agency', 0.9, 'N' from dual
)
select visitor_id,
       min(location_name) keep (dense_rank first order by adherence, distance) 
                                                                as location_name,
       min(distance) keep (dense_rank first order by adherence) as distance,
       min(adherence) as adherence
from   yourQueryResult
group by visitor_id;
```